# How to add custom fields to Joomla Estate Agency (JEA) extension

Tags: php, joomla

There is a a plug in called JEA which allows us to create a Joomla site for an estate agent. This is working well, but we would like to add a few extra fields to it.

Please can someone help me add in some extra fields by letting me know which files it is that need editing?

The plug-in can be found here:
http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jea/

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

JEA has a plugin system so don't hack the core files, create a plugin to add the fields.

There is an example plugin in svn you can find here http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/jea/wiki/?pagename=Plugins